# 10 years in system administration and yet can not contribute to serverfault

Tags: linux, windows, security

Is it me silly or I am doing something wrong? I was constantly learning during my System administrator career, but when I review serverfault or superuser questions I find myself very difficult to help somebody with their problems. When I say that I was constantly learning I mean that I tried to troubleshoot each problem that came to me from users. I not only tried to fix it, but understand why the problem happened. Fixing the problem = reinstall Windows. Understanding the problem - finding fault module in Windows and replacing or repairing it.
Perhaps may be my problem is that I am eager to learn too much topics: Linux, networking, Windows, security and it make it difficult to become expert enough to answer questions on serverfault. Serverfault is interesting for me because of job opportunities and personal pride.

Comment: This is off topic here. But seriously, given the extreme low effort some people put into the basics - I would assume a 2nd year sysadin can contribute here and there. 10 years and - well - half the relevant question should definitely be in your answer capacity. Otherwise I would question your career choice and your learning. Want some fun? I AM NOT EVEN A SYSADMIN. I just do that on the side. But I do RTFM.

Comment: This doesn't even really fit on [meta], where questions about the site should normally be asked.

Comment: @Link08: He means that many questions here are very basic and should be easy to answer, because people don't put any effort into trying to find a solution or asking a good question. I don't know where this could be posted, becuase frankly, I don't get what the point of your post is in the first place.